# Send Activity behavior when sending 2 emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio

I'm new in Marketing Cloud and I'm studying for Email Specialist cert. I'm not sure how the Send email activity works in Automation Studio for queuing emails.

If I need to send 2 emails, and I would like to send the second email right after the first one completed, I believe I would need to set two Send activities in Step 1 and Step 2 right?

Is there any case where I can have both Send email activities in the same Step and the second activity runs after the first one concludes?

To me, each activity listed in a step runs in parallel and if everything ends well, the next step continues, is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> To me, each activity listen in a step runs in parallel and if everything ends well, the next step continues, is this correct?

This is correct, hence you must place the email activities in two subsequent steps of your activity.